# How to find 11th entry in SQL Access database table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How would I find the 11th entry in an Access SQL database table? I have to use the TOP function, and my query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 11 Passenger.Name, SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) AS [Total Amount Spent on Tickets]
FROM Passenger INNER JOIN Manifest ON Passenger.PassengerNumber=Manifest.PassengerNumber
GROUP BY Passenger.Name
ORDER BY SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 T.Name, T.[Total Amount Spent on Tickets]
FROM

(SELECT TOP 11 Passenger.Name, SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) AS [Total Amount Spent on Tickets]
FROM Passenger INNER JOIN Manifest ON Passenger.PassengerNumber=Manifest.PassengerNumber
GROUP BY Passenger.Name
ORDER BY SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) DESC) As T

ORDER BY T.[Total Amount Spent on Tickets] ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 11 Passenger.Name, SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) AS [Total Amount Spent on Tickets]
FROM Passenger INNER JOIN Manifest ON Passenger.PassengerNumber=Manifest.PassengerNumber
GROUP BY Passenger.Name
ORDER BY SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: There is no "LIMIT" keyword in access. I believe the answer is to use a nested "TOP" query: 

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(SELECT TOP 11 Passenger.Name, SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) AS [Total Amount Spent on Tickets]
FROM Passenger INNER JOIN Manifest ON Passenger.PassengerNumber=Manifest.PassengerNumber
GROUP BY Passenger.Name
ORDER BY SUM(Manifest.Ticketprice) DESC);