# Get the n'th record for every SerialNumber

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID | SerialNumber | SomeData
---|--------------|---------
1  | 1            | abc
2  | 1            | def
3  | 1            | ghi
4  | 1            | jkl
5  | 2            | mno
6  | 2            | pqr
```

Now i want a query that returns 'SomeData' for every n'th ID of every serial number(if that n'th ID exists for that serial number). So if `n=2`, the output i'd like is:

```
ID | SerialNumber | SomeData
---|--------------|---------
2  | 1            | def
6  | 2            | pqr
```

I think this is already half the solution, but i can't figure out how to make it do what i want it to: [How to find 11th entry in SQL Access database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891320/how-to-find-11th-entry-in-sql-access-database-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access is a lousy database for this sort of thing.  You can enumerate the values with a subquery and then use that for the selection:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from <your table> as t2
              where t2.serialnumber = t.serialnumber and t2.id <= t.id
             ) as seqnum
      from <your table> as t
     ) as t
where seqnum = 2;
```

The middle subquery is not actually needed.  You could put the correlated subquery in the `where` clause.  I find this form clearer in intent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, could you please say which 't' or 't2' i have to replace by the name of my table? I can't completly figure it out.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please take a look at my extra question?

Comment: @KobeFl . . . Questions should be asked as *new questions*, not in comments and not by editing already answered questions.